# Tablelayout dependence between the lines

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I have very atypical problem.
I create talelayout programmatically, Inner tablelayout i have 2 rows.

In first i have 1x textview
In second is 4x textview

If text in firstrow's occupies a lot of space, then textviews in secondrow are not distribute fine

```
Firstrow
+---------------------------+
|          |                |   
|          |                |   
+---------------------------+
Secondrow
+---------------------------+
||         |     |     |    |
||         |     |     |    |
||         |     |     |    |
||         |     |     |    |
+---------------------------+
```

I use this code to distribute space, when i use only secondrow it works fine but when tablelayout have 2 rows it doesn't work by a rows dependency

```
  TableRow.LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0.25f);
```

Tablelayout should look like this

```
Firstrow
+---------------------------+
|          |                |   
|          |                |   
+---------------------------+
Secondrow
+---------------------------+
||     |      |      |      |
||     |      |      |      |
||     |      |      |      |
||     |      |      |      |
+---------------------------+
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Try working with linear layouts. They have a property called android:weight. That might be of some use to you

Comment: wow it works, i put secondrow to linearlayout and then linearlayout to tablelayout and thats it, it works perfect, tkanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `txtview.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

`MAX_VALUE` is 2 or 3 or so on...

By using this code you can set the space of both textviews without affecting each other.